# iOS: Detect SMS / Email Recipients

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

Is it possible to check how many of the recipients of your mail or sms successfully received the message you are sending? For instance I will send an SMS to 5 people and only 3 people received the message actually, how can I programmatically identify the number of recipients that actually receives my message? Please help me guys.. I'm really stuck with this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. SMS messaging is a one-way data flow. You send the message and the network will try to send it on. There is no receipt mechanism.

When they introduced iMessage, that has a delivery receipt mechanism (although it isn't always 100% correct) and can also mark if it has been read (if the recipient has read receipt turned on). But that isn't available for you to access programatically.

So, the short answer to your question is

No.

Comment: thanks nick.. but is it the same with the sending of email? is there also no way to determine the number of successful sending?

Comment: No, it's not possible outside of the email standards.

Comment: SMS isn't a one-way data flow. My Nokia N9 showed delivery receipts for every SMS I sent, and I tested it with another phone on airplane mode (a cheap T9 Samsung), and I the N9 only showed "Delivered" when the other phone actually received the message, so it was working on Brazil.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS application, the answer may be "NO".

However, I am sorry to disagreed with Nick.
SMS was defined to have two-way communication between Message center and mobile terminal (MT). End user should be allow to read the SMS recipient.

If you want more information, you can check GSM Technical Specification (phase2+).
http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gts/03/0340/05.03.00_60/gsmts_0340v050300p.pdf

or in general language as following link: 
http://www.developershome.com/sms/sms_tutorial.asp?page=basicConcepts

All the world mobile hand set developer (including Apple) should follow this industrial standard.

I found the "SMS recipient" setting from other mobile device, but NO iPhone.

In short, SMS support 2-way messaging, but Apple do follow the rule.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, but NOT yet evaluated:
If build the SMS with your own application, you can try to add "heading" before as following link. Please share with us for you test with the message in this page after you try.

http://www.thinkjim.com/2008/07/sms-delivery-reports-on-iphone-3g.html

Answer (score 0):

As I want to have the answer too, so I just google around.
and found a answer seem make sense.

This is the answer from offical iOS developer guide.
Wish this can help.

If the user requests that the message be sent, the system queues it for delivery and invokes the delegate object’s messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult: method. The result is one of “sent,” “cancelled,” or “failed.”

Details:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1